# How to set number to zero if it's below zero?

Tags: python

i am making a code for a dice rolling game. i want to make it so that the score of a player can never go below zero. any ideas?

```
from random import choice
print("Lets Play")
play1 = input("Player 1 name: ")
play2 = input("Player 2 name: ")
print("Hi " + play1 + " & " + play2 + ", let" + "'" + "s roll the dice")

die = list(range(2, 13))

d_1 = choice(die)
print(play1, "Your number is...\n{}".format(d_1))

d_2 = choice(die)
print(play2, "Your number is...\n{}".format(d_2))

if not d_1 % 2:
    d_1 += 10
else:
    d_1 -= 5

if not d_2 % 2:
    d_2 += 10
else:
    d_2 -= 5
if d_1 <= 0:
    print ("test")

if d_2 <= 0:
    d_2.append(0)
print (play1, "Your total points is",d_1)
print (play2, "Your total points is",d_2)
```

Comment: Your indentation is completely wrong.

Comment: Please make an effort to reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. If readers have to try and guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems or introduce new ones into the program.

Answer (score 0):

Since `d_2` is an integer and not a list, instead of doing this (which makes an error since you cannot append to a integer);

```
if d_2 <= 0:
    d_2.append(0)
```

You should have it like this;

```
if d_2 < 0:
    d_2 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a dictionary and handle all those if repeating `if/else` at once. To handle the less than 0 just set up a condition before printing the `odd` manipulated score

```
dicta = {play1: d_1, play2: d_2}

for k, v  in dicta.items():
    if not v % 2:
        print(k, "your total points are", v+10)
    else:
        if v - 5 < 0:
            print(k, "your total points are", 0)
        else:
            print(k, "your total points are", v-5)
```